# DEXT. How to set property for SCSI device created by UserCreateTargetForId()

Tags: macos, iokit, scsi, driverkit

For my KEXT I set the property “Protocol Characteristics” in **Info.plist** file

```
<key>Protocol Characteristics</key>
<dict>
    <key>Physical Interconnect</key>
    <string>SAS</string>
    <key>Physical Interconnect Location</key>
    <string>External</string>
</dict>
```

For DEXT this method does not work - still my SCSI device has “Internal/External” property instead of “External”
Protocol Characteristics

```
<dict>
    <key>Physical Interconnect</key>
    <string>SCSI Parallel Interface</string>
    <key>Physical Interconnect Location</key>
    <string>Internal/External</string>
</dict>
```

I also tried to set these properties by the second parameter for UserCreateTargetForId(). It also did not work.

Does anybody know how to set the property?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is for a dext implementing `IOUserSCSIParallelInterfaceController`?

I've not tested it myself, but have you tried calling `UserSetTargetProperties()` in your controller?

Comment: 1) Yes it is  dext implementing 'IOUserSCSIParallelInterfaceController'
2) Yes i have tried to call UserSetTargetProperties() without result too.
Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Update OS to current state and setup properties by using 'Info.plist' has worked correct for me.